# Flutter GetX file observer

Tags: flutter, file, flutter-getx, observers

I'm new to flutter/getx, trying to write an app which shows profile picture stored on Firebase storage and can replace it by picking a new image.
I'm using flutter_cache_manager to cache the images.

The issue is that how to show the image after it's retrieved from Firebase. Or after new image was uploaded and the app needs to show the newly uploaded image.

Here is my controller:

```
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

import 'controllers.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_cache_manager/flutter_cache_manager.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class ProfilePictureController extends GetxController {
  static ProfilePictureController get to => Get.find();
  final ThemeController themeController = ThemeController.to;
  final FirebaseStorage _storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
  static const cacheKey = "profilePictureCacheKey";
  final cacheManager = CacheManager(
    Config(
      cacheKey,
      stalePeriod: const Duration(days: 1),
      maxNrOfCacheObjects: 1000,
      repo: JsonCacheInfoRepository(databaseName: cacheKey),
    )
  );

  Future<File> upload(userId, path) async {
    // Create a Reference to the file
    Reference ref = _storage
        .ref()
        .child('profile-pictures')
        .child(userId)
        .child('live.jpg');

    final metadata = SettableMetadata(
      contentType: 'image/jpeg',
    );

    var file = File(path);
    ref.putFile(file, metadata);
    cacheManager.putFile(await _getURL(userId), file.readAsBytesSync(), key: _getCacheKey(userId));
    return file;
  }

  Future<File> download(userId) async {
    try {
      final url = _getURL(userId);
      return await cacheManager.getSingleFile(await url, key: _getCacheKey(userId));
    } on IOException {
      String defaultImage = 'images/default.png';
      if (themeController.isDarkModeOn == true) {
        defaultImage = 'images/defaultDark.png';
      }
      return _getImageFileFromAssets(defaultImage);
    }
  }

  Future<String> _getURL(userId) {
    return _storage
        .ref()
        .child("profile-pictures")
        .child(userId)
        .child('live.jpg')
        .getDownloadURL();
  }

  String _getCacheKey(userId) {
    return 'profile-pictures/$userId/live.jpg';
  }

  Future<File> _getImageFileFromAssets(String path) async {
    final byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/$path');

    final file = File('${(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/$path');
    await file.writeAsBytes(byteData.buffer.asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes));

    return file;
  }
}
```

I'm not sure how my UI code should look like to update the image. This is a little messy since I'm trying to experiment:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_cache_manager/flutter_cache_manager.dart';
import 'package:get/get_rx/src/rx_types/rx_types.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import '../../controllers/profile_picture_controller.dart';
import '/models/models.dart';
import '/ui/components/components.dart';

class Avatar extends StatelessWidget {
  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
  ProfilePictureController profilePictureController = ProfilePictureController.to;
  Rx<File> file = Rx(File("assets/images/default.png"));


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      child: Hero(
        tag: 'User Avatar Image',
        child: CircleAvatar(
            foregroundColor: Colors.blue,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            radius: 70.0,
            child: ClipOval(
              child: Image.file(
                file.value,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                width: 240.0,
                height: 240.0,
              ),
            )
        ),
      ),
      onTap: () async {
        // Get the file from the image picker and store it
        final XFile? image = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery, maxWidth: 512);

        if (image == null) {
          return;
        }

        await profilePictureController.upload("1234", image.path);
        file.value = await profilePictureController.download("1234");
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was missing `Obx(() =>` , this fixed the issue of image not updating:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      child: Hero(
        tag: 'User Avatar Image',
        child: CircleAvatar(
            foregroundColor: Colors.blue,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            radius: 70.0,
            child: ClipOval(
              child: Obx(() => Image.file( // Added Obx(() => 
                file.value,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                width: 240.0,
                height: 240.0,
              )),
            )
        ),
      ),
      onTap: () async {
        // Get the file from the image picker and store it
        final XFile? image = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery, maxWidth: 512);

        if (image == null) {
          return;
        }

        await profilePictureController.upload("1234", image.path);
        file.value = await profilePictureController.download("1234");
      },
    );
  }
```